# Java Static final instances hierarchy deserialization

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I have 3 classes:

```
public class Base {
  private int code;
  private static final Map<String, Map<Integer, Base>> ALL_MAPS = 
  new HashMap<>();

 protected Base(int code) {
  this.code = code;
  getConstMap(this.getClass()).put(code, this);
}

protected Map<Integer, Base> getConstMap(Class<?> clazz) {
  Map<Integer, Base> res;
  if ((res = ALL_MAPS.get(clazz.getName())) == null) {
     res = new HashMap<>();
     ALL_MAPS.put(clazz.getName(), res);
  }
  return res;
}
//...
}

public class AConstants extends Base {
   public static final AConstants A_1 = new AConstants(1, 
 "sample1");
 public static final AConstants A_2 = new AConstants(2, "sample2");
   //...
   private final String text;
   private AConstants(int code, String text) {
      super(code);
      this.text = text;
   }
}

public class BConstants extends Base {
   public static final BConstants B_1 = new BConstants(1, 
"sample1", "moreText");
   public static final BConstants B_2 = new BConstants(2, 
"sample2", "moreText");
   //...
   private final String text;
   private final String moreText;
   private BConstants(int code, String text, String moreText) {
      super(code);
      this.text = text;
      this.moreText = moreText;
   }
}
```

What I want to achieve is having a base method for deserializing (and serealizing) static final instances in the `Base` class. Obviously, I can't do smth like this due to generic type being unable to be referenced from static context during compilation (plus I obviously can't get the class of `CONST`):

```
@JsonCreator
public static CONST deserialize(@JsonProperty("code") int code) {
    // Should get the class of CONST and retrieve static final instance by code
    return ALL_MAPS.get(CONST.class).get(code);
}

@JsonValue
public Integer serialize() {
    // Return code for static final instance of the necessary class
    return getKeyByValue(ALL_MAPS.get(CONST.class), this);
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this with Jackson? Or if not, how do I write a custom serializer/deserializer for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has a similiar use case, here's how I did it. `Base` class is basically a placeholder for all the `static final` instances (or should I call them `constants`) - `ALL_MAPS` contains key as the name of the class which extends `Base` and as of value - a `Map` of keys - code of the instance and the instance itself as value. When the subclass of `Base` is loaded into the JVM, all the `constants` in it (as they are `static`) are placed in the `ALL_MAP`. So when deserializing, apart from loading the class into the memory, I only need a class of the `constant` and a key to it (`code`). I can get the class in the custom deserializer just like this: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2711

After that, all is left is to load the class into memory - I achieved it via reflection by calling `get` method on any static field with `null` value as I don't want to allow creating instances of `const` subclasses at all. And then - to read the json node which contains the `code` and get the `constant`.

As a note: on the `Base` class I used `@JsonDeserialize(using = BaseConstDeserializer.class)` where `BaseConstDeserializer` is the custom deserializer.

Here is the code of the deserializer:

```
public class BaseConstDeserializer<CONST extends BaseConst> extends StdDeserializer<CONST> implements ContextualDeserializer {
private final Class<CONST> deserializedFieldClazz;

protected BaseConstDeserializer(Class<CONST> deserializedFieldClazz) {
    super(BaseConst.class);
    this.deserializedFieldClazz = deserializedFieldClazz;
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public CONST deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JacksonException {
    JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
    Integer code = JsonUtils.readSingleNode(node, "code", JsonNode::asInt, ValidUtils::isInteger);
    if (code != null) {
        BaseConst.initConst(deserializedFieldClazz);
        return (CONST) BaseConst.getConstAndClearMap(code, deserializedFieldClazz);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext deserializationContext, BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
    Class<CONST> rawClass = (Class<CONST>) property.getType().getRawClass();
    return new BaseConstDeserializer<>(rawClass);
}
}
```

The only drawback I can guess here is that I need to manage the memory usage by myself - by clearing the map every time I deserialized json. I know that in Spring I can use `@Scope` to set the "lifespan" of an instance of bean to the scope of request but I don't like creating and having those instances in this case at all. This is propably an unorthodox approach, but it serves my case and I like the solution.
Anyway, if someone sees any other potentials cons and pros of it, I'd like to hear.